# Waiting for input with timeout

Tags: c, linux

When my program begins, I want to allow the user to hit a key to enter debug mode for one of the modules. Many of the solutions (involving `alarm()`, in particular) seemed complicated and involved multiple functions. Instead, I adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22420665/5560474):

```
// Check to see if we should enter GSM de-bug mode
fd_set          s;
struct timeval  timeout;

timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 100000;
int i = 100000;

do {
    printf("Press [ENTER] for GSM debug mode... %i  \r",i/10000); 
    fflush(stdout);
    FD_ZERO(&s);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &s);
    select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &s, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    i--;
} while (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &s) == 0 && i > 0);

if ( i <= 0 ) { printf("\nSkipping debug mode...\n"); }
else 
{ 
    printf("\nEntering debug mode...\n"); 

    // fill in the debug code here

}
```

This code works, based on a few quick tests, and exhibits the behavior I want. But, have I created any problems for myself?

Comment: So, each timeout is 0.1 seconds, and you iterate 100000 times, so you end up waiting for 10000 seconds (3 hours)?

Comment: No, it only takes about 10 seconds to complete.... I'm not sure of the actual function of the timeout struct. Is this waiting for a user to hit enter after typing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Must reset timeout

`select()` is allowed to modify your timeout value.  So for your program, what happens is that the first call to `select()` takes 0.1 seconds because of the timeout, but the timeout is then reduced to 0.  The next 99999 calls to `select()` have a zero timeout.  You should reset the timeout right before you call `select()`, like this:

```
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 100000;
select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &s, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
```

Once you do that, you no longer need 100000 iterations, because each iteration will have the proper 0.1 second timeout instead of returning "immediately".